# Is it safe to delete unused Linux kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, package-management, opensuse, upgrade

[image]

I don't want to use the 4.2.5-x kernel, I can't even boot with the proprietary Nvidia drivers. 3.16.7-24 kernel works fine.
Is it safe to remove all 4.2.5-x kernels and how to do so?

---

openSUSE 13.2

Comment: You usually do that via the package manager.  I don't know how on openSUSE, I know Debian.

Comment: and when you delete them, you may also need to run `update-grub` to remove them from the grub menu.  or your package manager will probably do that automatically as you add and remove kernel packages.

Comment: It is safe. More here: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Keep_multiple_kernel_versions

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to delete unused kernels. But I would suggest to keep at least one  kernel in case you have troubles with the newly installed kernel.